# Why function uses the global variable and skip the local one when we have 2 variables with the same identifier

Tags: c, function, scope

As far as I know that when I use a function it creates a stack frame nested from the main stack frame and depending on that it's supposed that when a variable being referenced to and it isn't declared in the function scope the function gradually goes to the larger scope so here it should go to the Local scope before it jump to the Global, or I'm misunderstanding it ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int X = 2;
void Scope(void);

int main()
{
    int X = 3;
    Scope();

    return 0;
}
void Scope(void)
{
    printf("Entering X = %d\n" ,X);
    printf("Exiting  X = %d\n" , X*X);
}
```

Comment: The variable `X` in `main()` can't be seen from function `Scope()`. It's *out of scope*. In C functions are not nested.

Comment: In fact this shouldn't compile. C doesn't allow `X = 2;` outside of a function.

Comment: @WeatherVane Pre-C99 that was allowed (I think); like functions, the declaration defaults to `int`. MSVC accepts the code as is: *warning C4431: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C no longer supports default-int*

Comment: @AdrianMole it's still the only `X` visible by `Scope()`.

Comment: @AdrianMole As I recall K&R C (pre-C89) required that global variables still declare a type and that it was only functions that had a default type.

Comment: The `X` used inside the `Scope` function is the global `X` (the one declared with `X = 2;`). BTW it should be `int X = 2;`. Visibility of variables (fortunately) do not depend on the call stack.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sure. I'm not challenging your scope assertion, at all. Just saying that (some) early C compilers allowed such 'default int' declarations. MSVC was/is one.

Comment: @AdrianMole you are right, MSVC 2022 doesn't even warn at my usual setting -W3.

Comment: @Anthony C Howe – Instead of a type, a storage class or a type qualifier was also sufficient in a global variable declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `X` from main is not visible from function `Scope` as Scope is a separate function and it does not see automatic storage duration variables from other functions. It can only see the "global" or compilation unit static storage duration variables.